# prism - region not loading contents of usercontrol in shell

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I was trying to learn prism, but I am unable to get a very basic example working. I have a Shell which has a single region. I am trying to load a view from module into a shell's region but the shell shows a blank window. I am just not able to figure out why the view is not loaded into the shell's region. Here are the code files.

BootStrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper {

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell() {
        Window shell = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
        return shell;
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }
}
```

Shell:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMPractice.MainWindow">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Module:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(CoreModule))]
public class CoreModule : IModule {

    [Import]
    public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

    public void Initialize() {
        var view = new WelcomeView();
        RegionManager.AddToRegion("MainRegion", view);
    }
}
```

View To Load in Region:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMPractice.Modules.Core.WelcomeView">

<Grid Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello Prism!" FontSize="20" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The above view should show up in the shell, but it doesn't. Any ideas why shell's region does not show the above view ?

**EDIT:**
The Module is configured through the App.config file as given below.

App.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, 
                                  Microsoft.Practices.Prism"/>
  </configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="MVVMPractice.Modules.Core.dll" 
            moduleType="MVVMPractice.Modules.Core.CoreModule, MVVMPractice.Modules.Core.CoreModule, 
                       Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 
            moduleName="CoreModule" 
            startupLoaded="true" />
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why dont you call `RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", view)`, instead of adding the view to the region. It seems to me that it only adds it to the region and not show it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get a blank window. The view somehow does not end up in the "MainRegion".

Comment: well it should. You can check this by calling the RegionManager.Regions["MainRegion"] in code or use it in the localwindow by debugging it. Else Try setting a Width and a Height to both the ContentControl and the usercontrol you are loading. It might be possible that it isnt properly sized

Comment: The View is there in the regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].ActiveViews collection and is the only view in that collection. I can confirm that from debugger. So ideally the Text should appear on the screen, but it just doesn't.

Comment: like I said it must be a styling problem. Your stackpanel (in the window) isnt stretch. try replacing it with a grid. or you can just set the width and height

Comment: As suggested by you earlier, when I apply the width and height property of content control and and User control that is placed in the control, I get a blank space (of that height and width). That is the ContentControl seems to be honoured by wpf, but the UserControl (the View) doesn't show up in that space. I don't think its style problem given the above fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, although I haven't attempted to use app.config configuration yet:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    #region Overrides of Bootstrapper

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (MainWindow) Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(CoreModule).Assembly));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

// Core module the same as yours

// Main window (Shell)

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"  />
```

Your Xaml works but since you have used a StackPanel the region doesn't fill the view.

Comment: Phil, I have edited my question to indicate how I am configuring module using configuration file. I think that should be fine for the module to be discovered. Also, I can see that the Initialize() method of my Module is getting invoked. The only thing is that the region does not get populated with the view I am trying to add. Thanks for looking into the question.

Comment: Phil, Thanks for trying code out and posting here. I can see from your code that I was missing the InitializeShell() in my Bootstrapper. The intersting part was the Window was still loading up. That was because I had failed to remove the "StartupUri" attribute in my App.xaml. Thanks a lot for helping me resolve the issue.

Comment: Phil, I have excepted the answer. Sorry for the delay